# TPL Dataflow controlling max degree of parallelism between nested blocks

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Let's say I have an action block A that perform some work in parallel with a max degree of parallelism of 4.

Say I have case where action block A is doing work X in some cases and work Y in others. X is some small work, Y is some larger work that requires it to be split into smaller work chunks and therefore I need to parallelise those too.
Inside work Y I therefore need to parallelise the work chunks to a max degree of 4, but at this point I might have 4 A blocks executing in parallel which could lead for example to "A-X, A-X, A-Y, A-Y" running in parallel. This would result in 1 + 1 + 4 + 4 parallel tasks which is too many parallel tasks for my purpose as I would always keep it limited to a maximum of 4 (or any other chosen number) overall.

Is there a way to control the maximum degree of parallelism including nested blocks?

Comment: Can post the relevant code? It is unclear what exactly you mean by _nested blocks_. In general though if you have _work X and work Y_ then you would have `BlockX` and `BlockY`. Now if those have the same input and output types then you would link a buffer to each with an appropriate `Predicate` to sort _work X_ from _work Y_.

Comment: If you want to impose a concurrency limitation that exceeds the boundaries of a single block, then you could take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400875/dataflow-tpl-implementing-pipeline-with-precondition/62356881#62356881) answer for the available options.

Answer (score 2):

While creating a block in TPL Dataflow, you can specify a custom scheduler for the block via [its options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions?view=netcore-2.0).

Easy way to limit the number of concurrent tasks and concurrency level is to use the [ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194750.aspx) in your code, with parameters you need.